# Why is my input not showing up as activeElement when tabbing?

Tags: javascript, html

When I tab through my elements, my inputs don't show up in the console, but the button does when I tab out of the button, why aren't the inputs showing up in the console?

```js
(function() {
  let element = document.getElementById('MyDiv');
  let focusables = element.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], button:not([disabled])');
  //console.log(focusables);

  let firstFocusableElement = focusables[0];
  let lastFocusableElement = focusables[focusables.length - 1];

  //console.log(firstFocusableElement);
  //console.log(lastFocusableElement);

  element.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Tab') {
      if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableElement) {
        console.log(document.activeElement);
        firstFocusableElement.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });

})();
```

```css
#MyContainer {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#MyDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 500px;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyContainer">
  <div id="MyDiv">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="FirstName">
        Name: <input id="txtName" />
      </div>

      <br />
      <div id="MiddleName">
        Middle Name: <input id="txtMiddle" />
      </div>

      <br />
      <div id="LastName">
        Last Name: <input id="txtLast" />
      </div>

      <br />
      <div>
        <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. When you get your `focusables`, you use `input[type="text"]` as your selector for your text inputs but in your html none of your inputs have a `type` attribute of `text` and therefore none of them will match.
2. Before logging, you check: `if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableElement)` which means it will only fire for your last element (the button)